# Background image expands when modal window pops up if there is a scrollBar. React Bootsrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

It seems to me that my problem isn't difficult, but I don't how enough experience.

It simple project on React Bootsrap. Have a component Jumbotrone with "parallax effect":

```
background: `no-repeat fixed bottom url(${props.background})`,
backgroundSize: 'cover',
position: relative;
z-index: -2;
```

And there are buttons that call a modal window component from rect-bootsrap. When it opens, backround-image expands by a couple of pixels, and shrinks when it close.

This happens if there is a scrollbar. Because of it, the document.clientWidth changes every time the modal window is called and closes(window.innerWidth doesen't change). But nothing will move, except for the background image.

I tried to leave scrolling in a modal window - the picture does not move, but the rest of the elements move down.

You can see it on the About tab by clicking on any of the buttons.

Please explain why this is happening:)

deploy page: https://goodnightbuddy.github.io/web-dev-blog/

repository: https://github.com/GoodNightBuddy/web-dev-blog

Answer (score 2):

As an option:

```
body {   overflow-y: overlay; }
```

Scrollbar will apear over the document, so it is not change document sizes.